# SSRS report deployment in distributed server

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

Hi I am new to SSRS report deployement. I currently have 3 server web server,app server and db server. Now my concern is where should I deploy the report ? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is a server side report (.RDL), Please follow the below steps,

1. Login to **Database server**
2. Open "Reporting Services Configuration Manager" (Start Menu) and connect to SSRS
3. Click on Report Manager URL
4. Open the URL in IE (default path is http:///Reports/
5. Upload your (RDL) and Configure the datasources et..

You can also deploy using one of the following methods on the SSRS Server (Which is the by default the Database server )

1. RS Utility
2. Programatically C# code with Web Service Reference ( http:///ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx)
3. Visual Studio (BIDS)
4. Open the RDL file in the Report Builder and Save in the SSRS Report Server path(  http:///ReportServer)

I hope this helps.